# Knex migration issues

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have 7 different schemas in my application(Postgres) , i did two migrations to alter columns , one affected A schema and one affected the public schema . I wanted to know the reason for this unexpected behaviour .

Comment: Some code what be super awesome

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to guess with given details. I'll guess anyways that you haven't given https://knexjs.org/#Migrations-API `schemaName` for migrations in your knex configuration.